# HTTP Function to update all documents in a collection using collectionGroup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am trying to update all the documents in a collection using **.collectionGroup** but I am getting this error in the return of my function:

> 'Error: could not handle the request'

Here is my code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const createTypeOfPaymentHTTP = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collectionGroup("payments")
      .get()
      .then(async (snapshot) => {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const amount = doc.data().amount;
          let type_of_payment: string;
          if (amount === 400 || amount === 350 || amount === 300) {
            type_of_payment = "monthly_pay";
          } else if (amount === 855 || amount === 997 || amount === 1140) {
            type_of_payment = "three_months_pay";
          } else if (amount === 1620 || amount === 1890 || amount === 2160) {
            type_of_payment = "six_months_pay";
          } else if (amount === 2880 || amount === 3360 || amount === 3840) {
            type_of_payment = "one_year_pay";
          } else {
            type_of_payment = "no_debt_related";
          }
          promises.push(doc.ref.update({ type_of_payment: type_of_payment })); // Update last_payment field
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then(() => response.send("Job Done"));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
      });
  });
```

Is there any way around this or I am doing something wrong?
Just starting with Firebase Functions, Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Here is my database structure

[Data Base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btnfY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I found out two things after a few tries, first there where some collections that didn't had any documents on them so I added:

`if (doc.exists)`

And the other thing was that the default memory allocated by default is 256 MiB and it was getting the error:

> Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

Moved the function to 2 GiB fixed that one.

So those two changes fixed that

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with only one modification for this line:

```
let type_of_payment: string;
```

To

```
let type_of_payment = "";
```

But I don't think that could be the issue. Anyway in my case it worked perfectly making the changes in Firestore and returning `Job Done`. You may want to use the `console.log` for an old school debug and see where is the step that is failing or check the logs.

Note that the Firebase Functions behind the scenes are GCP Cloud Functions, so you can go to the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) -> Logging and view the logs of the function.